# How can I do editable GridView in WEB C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How can I do editable GridView in WEB C#?

Comment: Maybe this MSDN link helps: [How to: Customize Controls for Editing in the GridView Web Server Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stk0x9y3%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture GridView.OnRowEditing event and set the AutoGenerateEditButton attribute to "True"... [see this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowediting.aspx)